# Regexp to match every occurence after n occurences

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

given some csv data, with unescaped commas in the final field like this

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
a, b, c, d, foo bar
a, b, c, d, Lorem Ipsum, dolores umbridge, something latin
a, b, c, d, upcoming unescaped commas!, one, two, three, oh no!
```

I want a regexp to match all the commas after the 4th comma on each line so I can replace them with an escaped comma \,

This is my terrible attempt so far which seems to return only the last occurence after the first n occurences.

```
^([^,]*,){4}([^,]*(,)[^,]*)*
```

For some context

Some formats which claim to be partially compatible with csv formats like [ASS](http://moodub.free.fr/video/ass-specs.doc) assume that it's ok to have **unescaped** commas in the **last** field because the number of fields was registered when the header line was parsed.

You can see this in the ASS specification

> The format line specifies how SSA will interpret all following Event lines. The field names must be spelled correctly, and are as follows:
>   `Marked, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text`
>   The last field will always be the Text field, so that it can contain commas.

and here

> The information fields in each line are separated by a commas.
>   This makes it illegal to use commas in character names and style names (SSA prevents you putting commas in these). It also makes it quite easy to load chunks of an SSA script into a spreadsheet as a CSV file, and chop out columns of information you need for another subtitling program.

To be able to parse files like this, assuming you've already separated the data into "Chunks", I need to also escape all the commas in the last field to work with certain [csv-parser](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/)s.

Comment: What's your target environment? Specifically, does it support the new lookbehind being added in ES2018? (Up-to-date versions of Node.js do, for instance, I believe.)

Comment: You could replace every comma with an escaped comma, then go back through and replace the first four escaped commas with regular commas. Not the greatest solution, but it's a quick workaround.

Comment: I left the target environment out, because I don't necessarily want to do it in javascript or Node.js. That's just what the csv parser is written in. I'm perfectly happy just doing it in my editor "vscode" or "atom", or in any language that someone provides a working solution.

Comment: Do you have at least 4 columns? I mean is there any chance for columns to be three or two?

Comment: For csv you should not escape the comma's but enclose the fields in `"`: `a,b,c,d,"more,data"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

- If you're doing this in an environment that supports the new lookbehind, and you have an array of strings
- If you aren't, or you have one big string

### If you can use lookbehind and have an array of strings

If you're doing this in an environment like Node.js that supports lookbehind (which will be in the ES2018 specification), you can do it like this:

```
const newData = data.map(line => line.replace(/(?<=(?:.*,){4,}.*),/g, "\\,"));
```

(I can only get this to work if you have an array of lines (which is what I thought you had). See the non-lookbehind version below if you have one big string.)

That's a positive lookbehind for at least four occurrences of `.*,` followed by `.*`. It matches every comma with that in front of it.

Example (if you have an array of lines):

```js
const data = [
  "1, 2, 3, 4, 5",
  "a, b, c, d, foo bar",
  "a, b, c, d, Lorem Ipsum, dolores umbridge, something latin",
  "a, b, c, d, upcoming unescaped commas!, one, two, three, oh no!",
];
const newData = data.map(line => line.replace(/(?<=(?:[^,]*,){4,}.*),/g, "\\,"));
console.log(newData);
```

### If you can't use lookbehind or have one big string

If you can't use lookbehind, you could capture the text before the relevant commas and use `replace` on the text after, with the function callback version of `replace`:

```
const newData = data.map(line =>
    line.replace(/^((?:[^,]*,){4})(.*)$/, (m, c0, c1) => c0 + c1.replace(/,/g, "\\,"))
);
```

Example (if `data` is an array):

```js
const data = [
  "1, 2, 3, 4, 5",
  "a, b, c, d, foo bar",
  "a, b, c, d, Lorem Ipsum, dolores umbridge, something latin",
  "a, b, c, d, upcoming unescaped commas!, one, two, three, oh no!",
];
const newData = data.map(line => line.replace(/^((?:[^,]*,){4})(.*)$/, (m, c0, c1) => c0 + c1.replace(/,/g, "\\,")));
console.log(newData);
```

Or if `data` is one big string:

```
const newData = data.replace(/^((?:[^,]*,){4})(.*)$/gm, (m, c0, c1) => c0 + c1.replace(/,/g, "\\,"));
```

Example (if `data` is one big string):

```js
const data =
`1, 2, 3, 4, 5
a, b, c, d, foo bar
a, b, c, d, Lorem Ipsum, dolores umbridge, something latin
a, b, c, d, upcoming unescaped commas!, one, two, three, oh no!`;
const newData = data.replace(/^((?:[^,]*,){4})(.*)$/gm, (m, c0, c1) => c0 + c1.replace(/,/g, "\\,"));
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could match till 4th occurrence of comma then capture remaining commas using:

```
^(?:[^,]*,){1,4}|(,)
```

Since `.replace()` method accepts a callback for its second parameter you could check within that callback whether first capturing group exists.

JS code:

```js
var str = `1, 2, 3, 4, 5
a, b, c, d, foo bar
a, b, c, d, Lorem Ipsum, dolores umbridge, something latin
a, b, c, d, upcoming unescaped commas!, one, two, three, oh no!`

console.log(
  str.replace(/^(?:[^,]*,){1,4}|(,)/gm, function($0, $1) {
     return $1 ? '\\' + $1 : $0;
  })
);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you think less about regex, a solution may be easier to find. Try something like this:

```
var result = "";
myCsvString.split('\n').forEach( (line) => {
    var count = 0;
    // /,/g means every occurrence of the character ','
    line = line.replace(/,/g, function(){ 
        if(++count > 4) { 
            return "\\,"
        } 
        return ","
    })
    result += line + '\n';
});
```

Comment: It gets a little uglier when you have to deal with multiple lines.  It would be nice if that `count` variable could be automatically reset on each iteration.

Comment: The doesn't seem to try to handle multiple lines at all.

Comment: It doesn't handle multiple lines, I figured rigging that up was trivial, but I will include it in the answer anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a regex for that?
You can achieve that with string & array manipulations.

```js
const csv = `1, 2, 3, 4, 5
a, b, c, d, foo bar
a, b, c, d, Lorem Ipsum, dolores umbridge, something latin
a, b, c, d, upcoming unescaped commas!, one, two, three, oh no!`;

const lines = csv.split('\n');

const result = lines.map((line) => {
  const commas = line.split(', ');
  const rest = commas.splice(4).join('\\, ');
  return commas.concat(rest).join(', ');
}).join('\n');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't he use regular expressions? This is exactly the kind of use they are made for.

Comment: I actually already wrote a solution in javascript, I wanted to know a solution in regex because it's fun learning how to do things in regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the lookbehind others suggested, then it might make sense to embed the count in a higher-order function:

```js
const allowReps = (n) => {
  let i = 0
  return (m, c) => (i++ < n) ? ',' : "\\," 
}

const data = [
  "1, 2, 3, 4, 5",
  "a, b, c, d, foo bar",
  "a, b, c, d, Lorem Ipsum, dolores umbridge, something latin",
  "a, b, c, d, upcoming unescaped commas!, one, two, three, oh no!",
];

const res = data.map(s => s.replace(/,/g, allowReps(4)))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: you could directly use the counter: `const allowReps = n => _ => n && n-- ? ',' : "\\,";`

Comment: @NinaScholz: Yes, that would be cleaner.  But I do have a pretty strong aversion to changing a function parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of answers here, but I figured it would hurt to point out that you can use array destructuring and the `...` operator if you know that the first *n* components are going to be there.

```js
const text = `1, 2, 3, 4, 5
a, b, c, d, foo bar
a, b, c, d, Lorem Ipsum, dolores umbridge, something latin
a, b, c, d, upcoming unescaped commas!, one, two, three, oh no!`

const formatted = text.split('\n').map(line => {
  [a, b, c, d, ...rest] = line.split(', ')
  return [a, b, c, d, rest.join('\\,')]
})

console.log(formatted)
```